# In Perl, how can I pass a variable as an argument to a subroutine?

Tags: perl, parameter-passing, subroutine

I am passing a scalar variable to subroutine in which I want to test if the argument matches a regex:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

print "Please enter your first name followed by your last name. For example: John Smith.\n";

chomp(my $name = <STDIN>);

&analyze_name($name);

sub analyze_name {
    if ($_ =~ /^\w+\s+\w+$/) {
            print "You entered $_.";
                    } else {
            print "Incorrect convention";
    }
}
```

I am getting output with the following error

```
Please enter your first name followed by your last name. For example: John Smith.
firstname lastname
Incorrect convention
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at /home/jhusbands/scripts/examples/test.pl line 13, <STDIN> line 1.
```

My thinking is it would pass `$name` to the "magic variable" `$_`.  I need to reuse this subroutine on multiple `<STDIN>` variables. How do I initialize `$_`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument to your subroutine is not in `$_`. It's in the array `@_`, and you need to get it out.

```
sub analyze_name {
    my $name = shift; # implicitly shifts @_
    if ($name =~ m/.../) { ... }
}
```

Or alternatively as a list assignment

```
sub analyze_name {
    my ($name) = @_;
    ....
}
```

Or, if you wanted to operate on the `@_` array directly

```
sub analyze_name {
    if ($_[0] =~ m/.../) { ... }
}
```

Now we are accessing the first element in the array `@_`. The sign in front of the variable name (called a *sigil*) in Perl changes with the type of value that that expression returns. So for the array it's `@_`, but when you access an element, it becomes `$_[0]` because the value inside is scalar, which means it is only one value. This is different from `$_`, which is a scalar variable. The same thing is true about `@array`, `$array[4]` and the scalar variable `$array` (which is a badly chosen name).

In most cases you want to do either the `shift` or the list assignment. If you have two or three arguments, the list is often easier to read. If there are a lot of args, having them one per line makes sense. Operating on `@_` directly usually only makes sense if speed is an issue because your sub is called millions of times in your program. **My advice is to take readable code over brevity and go with properly named arguments**.

---

The `$name` in the above code is *lexical* to that subroutine. That means it exists only there, and every time you call that sub, you get a new `$name`. The variable name of the variable you pass in when you call it doesn't matter.

```
analyze_name($foo);
analyze_name($bar);
analyze_name('foobar');
```

All of those pass a value to the sub. The sub does not care about the variable name. In the sub, it's always `$name`. Outside of the sub, `$name` does not exist.

---

Note that you should not call subs with `&` in Perl. That used to be the syntax in Perl 4 about 20 years ago. In Perl 5 this `&foo()` has a special meaning that you probably do not want. Drop the `&`, and look for *subroutine prototypes* if you want to know more about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your code to work you need to change:

```
if ($_ =~ /^\w+\s+\w+$/) {
```

**To**

`if ($_[0] =~ /^\w+\s+\w+$/)` {

Perl's documentation, [perldoc perlsub](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) which is installed alongside `perl`, says:

> Any arguments passed in show up in the array @_ . 
>   ...
>    if you called a
>   function with two arguments, those would be stored in `$_[0]` and `$_[1]`
>   . The array @_ is a local array, but its elements are aliases for the
>   actual scalar parameters.

Instead using this I'd recommend you store your argument to a variable and also avoid calling subroutines with "&" as **simbabque** said in his answer , so:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

print "Please enter your first name followed by your last name. For example: John Smith.\n";

chomp(my $name = <STDIN>);

analyze_name($name);

sub analyze_name {
  my ( $name ) = @_;

    if ($name =~ /^\w+\s+\w+$/) {
            print "You entered $name.";
                    } else {
            print "Incorrect convention";
    }
}
```